# Automate package installation with dialog prompt?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, debian, sh

I'm automating some package installation. We have created the package in question, but let me explain first.

In part of the automation, I'm installing the package with a shell script using `dpkg -i`.

I'm already using the non-interactive backend, so it's trying to hide the dialog prompt asking for an IP address. However,  it doesn't default to an old value and tries to run a MySQL query without the host for the query (yes, I know, bad design; I didn't make the package).

Now, I can edit this package, but that limits the support team with this automation, as they will obviously only be able to patch to this version of the package, and not any previous versions. I'd rather avoid that if possible.

Despite searching, I can't seem to find a way to fill that out, had the thought of something like

```
dpkg -i some-package.deb <<< "127.0.0.1"
```

but that doesn't seem to work. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Is it a debconf question, or something like `read` in the postinst script?  If the latter, then the non-interactive debconf backend makes no difference.

Comment: To be clear, it uses something like: https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7488/15646379428_9881701e29_z.jpg

In the preinstall script

Comment: I think I may have found a solution, and considering the things I'm typing into google, this is actually the top question, if anyone else wants to do this, I'll post the answer that may work for me (still writing it). Don't use noninteractive, so that the dialog windows will show up. Instead run everything to screen to hide them, and in your screen session write your script using expect to provide the required input.

Comment: If you're using debconf, then you should just be able to seed it with `debconf-set-selections` or the like.